# Load the same jpg image with OpenCV3.0 and matlab but get different results

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Recently, I'm translating some pieces of codes from Matlab to C++. And I load the images(JPG) using `imread()` in OpenCV3 in my codes, but I never got the same result as MATLAB codes.After checking my codes several times, I'm suprised to find that the original data of image always have little diference from each other.

Just like this:

- channals: R    G     B
- OpenCV:  150  124   200
- MATLAB:  148  125   203

Then I use GDAL to read the same image and got the same result as MATLAB. So I want to known if there are always some errors when read JPG images using OpenCV3.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe different handling mechanism in color profile. But just guessing, I have no idea, neither.

Comment: thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Are you aware that opencv's imread stores images in BGR order? Other than that, no clue.

Comment: yes,of course!The fact is that every channal has the same problem.

Comment: That's because they use different libraries to decode jpeg. There are a few dupes also... I'll look for them